# how to concatenate two jagged arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays
One is:

```
[ [ 2, 'c' ],
  [ 2, 'e' ],
  [ 3, 'a' ],
  [ 3, 'b' ] ]
```

and another is :

```
[ 3, [ 1, 'g' ], [ 2, [ 1, 'd' ], [ 1, 'f' ] ] ]
```

how can I concatenate both and get output like

```
[ [ 2, 'c' ],
  [ 2, 'e' ],
  [ 3, 'a' ],
  [ 3, 'b' ],
  [ 3, [ 1, 'g' ], [ 2, [ 1, 'd' ], [ 1, 'f' ] ] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr1 = [ [ 2, 'c' ],
             [ 2, 'e' ],
             [ 3, 'a' ],
             [ 3, 'b' ] ];  
var arr2 = [ 3, [ 1, 'g' ], [ 2, [ 1, 'd' ], [ 1, 'f' ] ] ];
arr1.push(arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the spread operator? Please be aware that it's not supported in IE.

```
const x = 
    [ [ 2, 'c' ],
    [ 2, 'e' ],
    [ 3, 'a' ],
    [ 3, 'b' ] ];

const y = [ 3, [ 1, 'g' ], [ 2, [ 1, 'd' ], [ 1, 'f' ] ] ];

const z = [...x, y];

console.log(z);
```

Comment: but I have to put it in a loop. The code is  `var leastTwo=arr.slice(0,2);
 var theRest=arr.slice(2);
 var combFreq=leastTwo[0][0]+leastTwo[1][0];
 leastTwo.unshift(combFreq);
 console.log(leastTwo);
 arr=theRest.concat([leastTwo]);
 arr.sort();
 console.log(arr);`

Comment: Please update your original question to reflect what you actually need.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the additional array in extra brackets for use with [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

```js
var a = [[2, 'c'], [2, 'e'], [3, 'a'], [3, 'b']],
    b = [3, [1, 'g'], [2, [1, 'd'], [1, 'f']]];
  
console.log(a.concat([b]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: when I run the code like this I got 'object' instead of value of second array. Then what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

[`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?v=b) will merge two arrays into one array without changing the original arrays

## Code

```
const x = 
    [ [ 2, 'c' ],
    [ 2, 'e' ],
    [ 3, 'a' ],
    [ 3, 'b' ] ]

const y = [ 3, [ 1, 'g' ], [ 2, [ 1, 'd' ], [ 1, 'f' ] ] ];

const z = x.concat([y])
```

## Example

```js
const x = [
  [2, 'c'],
  [2, 'e'],
  [3, 'a'],
  [3, 'b']
]

const y = [3, [1, 'g'],
  [2, [1, 'd'],
    [1, 'f']
  ]
];

const z = x.concat([y])

console.log(z)
```